# Remove border in Android Gallery widget?

Tags: android

How would one go about removing the ugly grey boarder around the Gallery images?

Comment: Gallery widget or Gallery App? Can you post your layout xml?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exclude this line in your ImageAdapter to stop loading of that preset:

```
//imageBackground = ta.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 1);
```

Images might be overlapping after this, so go into your main.xml or whatever you are using for styling and add this to your Gallery, for padding around your gallery images, like a transparent border:

```
android:spacing="10px"
```

So that now the Gallery part of the XML will read:

```
<Gallery 
android:id="@+id/Gallery01" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:spacing="10px">
</Gallery>
```

Comment: Could I use padding instead of spacing ?

Answer (score 2):

Another way is setting  yourGallery.setUnselectedAlpha(1);
The last answer bring me troubles in other things.
Excuse me for my english!