# Gray background on top of images in Gallery?

Tags: android, gallery

I've followed [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344532/remove-border-in-android-gallery-widget) thread to remove the border that surrounds the Gallery, but the problem now is that I have a gray background on top of my images. Its like a transparent gray background comes on top of the images.
This happened after removing these lines from the ImageAdapter:

```
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
    TypedArray a = c.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
    mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
    a.recycle();
 }
```

and from the getView of the Adapter I removed:

```
    i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
```

Now I dont have a border but I have this gray panel.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end all I had to do to fix this problem is to add this line to my GetView():

```
i.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    i.setBackgroundResource(mImageIds[position]);
```

instead of

```
    i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
```

I don't know why, but it works for me!